# Shouldn't Typescript pick the most specific function implementation?

Tags: typescript

I have the following code:

```
type allPossibileTypes = 'my-first-type' | 'my-second-type' | 'my-third-type';
type genericFunction = (innerVariable: any) => void;

class A {
   doSomethingWith(inputType: 'my-first-type', callback: (innerVariable: string) => void);
   doSomethingWith(inputType: allPossibileTypes, callback: genericFunction);
   doSomethingWith(inputType: string, callback: any) {
      // function logic here
   }
}
```

If I try to call the function like this:

```
AInstance.doSomething('my-first-type', ...);
```

I expect that typescript will hint me to the `(innerVariable: string) => void` for the second parameter, yet instead, it hints me to the `genericFunction` type. Until now, I thought that when picking type hints, typescript will choose the most specific implementation that it can use, am I mistaken in this?

If yes, how could I achieve to define a function, which allows me to use as the first parameter, only specific strings, and on some concrete occasions, based on the first parameter, give me additional type hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to exclude  `'my-first-type'` from `allPossibileTypes` in your overloads:

```js
type allPossibileTypes = 'my-first-type' | 'my-second-type' | 'my-third-type';
type genericFunction = (innerVariable: any) => void;

class A {
    doSomethingWith(inputType: 'my-first-type', callback: (innerVariable: string) => void): void
    doSomethingWith(inputType: Exclude<allPossibileTypes, 'my-first-type'>, callback: genericFunction): void
    doSomethingWith(inputType: string, callback: any) {
        // function logic here
    }
}

new A().doSomethingWith('my-first-type', (a: string) => void 0); // ok
new A().doSomethingWith('my-first-type', (a: number) => void 0) // error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.0-dev.20211013#code/C4TwDgpgBAhgNnACgewM6oJYCMNwgFXAlSgF4oByAWxAFoAzDAJ1WFtEgqgB9KbbUEAMbIAdgBN2RLr2p1gAC2aSOECgG4AsAChVUAOYRREJhiEAxAK6ihwDGLJQAFBlHGmANRimYWPAC5YURAASjIAPigAN2QMcS1tHSE4GHQoAEEoAG8dKDyocWQAZWQqCEVXfQB1DEUXUTBLYEJIQLkGZlYpTgAaKCF4OCwYIQBrQPr3Lx8-CEDWU1F9MNJImLiQwPXxXPzCkrKKpZq610bmokCAUQAPZMtxCAAeQZR0bFwCIlQ+9sYWNiqCjhPoDBDDMaBQzuMxWGx2MSbaKxHbafIFYqlcpKY61BT1c4tOZQBaVUGDCHjIKhbK7dF5AD0DKg9GstnsoigcGQ+jMUAUJggdKgAF8dGLEtpjAB3DJOEIAOn2WKO1TxTj+nUB0j6Thg82Ai2WEWRcSgAAYQuooEyoMhRjoZXLFcrDji1XVNQDumpdfqoKJLFQsCYVmsURawraTExkEwdEA)

Without `Exclude` both versions with `number` and `string` are  valid

**P.S.**

```js
interface test { prop1: string, prop2: string };

type ToBool<T> = {
  [Prop in keyof T]: boolean
}

type Result = ToBool<test>
```

Comment: yep, that did the trick... still, seems a bit overkill for me, if I want to specify signatures for most of my types, that I have to manually exclude each type.

Comment: Maybe this help https://catchts.com/publish-subscribe . See second example

Comment: Please keep in mind, that intersection of functions produces overloading

Comment: Would it be possible somehow in typescript, to extend an interface by adding additional valid types to their properties?

Comment: @AdamBaranyai COuld you please provide an example?

Comment: `interface test { prop1: string, prop2: string};` let's say that this interface has around 300 properties, with differing types. Would it be possible to create a second interface, with the same properties, yet all the types in the second interface should be booleans? For the above example, the expected result would be: `interface testModified { prop1: boolean, prop2: boolean }`

Comment: @AdamBaranyai I made an update